# Error: Could not find or load main class io.druid.cli.Main

Tags: docker, druid

I am deploying Apache-druid image  using docker-compose. I am getting following error, 
Error: Could not find or load main class io.druid.cli.Main.

I have set CLASSPATH properly. Files are in CLASSPATH.

Any Pointers? Thanks for your help.

Thanks,
Shubhada

Answer (score 1):

If others run into similar issue, here's some more context. From Druid version 0.13.0 onwards, the config scripts need to use `org.apache.druid.cli.Main`. So if you are working on a prior version, and run into this error, change `io.druid.cli.Main` to `org.apache.druid.cli.Main` in your scripts. Better option is to upgrade cleanly to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I was using different version of Druid. Which has differnnt package hierarchy of the class Main. Changed it to correct one.

Comment: It would be great if you specified how you solved problem, which versions were working for you and which not. Also you can mark your own answer as solution, if it worked.